# How do I add VSCode to the PATH for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

The Code documentation suggests that it is added to the PATH during installation, but that did not seem to work for me (at least not in PowerShell). Where is it installed such that I can add it myself?

Comment: Is it not in the standard place where every piece of software is? Program Files.

Comment: No, it is in the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Code` as per the answer below.

Comment: Reinstall VSCode will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a good old restart of the box fixed the issue. Interestingly, merely restarting PowerShell or logging out and back in didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

- The install path is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Code`
- `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Code\bin` is added to the `PATH` by the installer, but it might be that tools such as PowerShell will pick this change up only until after a log off/log on or a restart

Comment: This folder is indeed added to the path, but it contains the `code.cmd` file which isn't working for me from PowerShell.

Comment: I added the following to my PowerShell profile that seems to do the trick:
`function code{Invoke-Expression("$HOME\AppData\Local\Code\bin\code.cmd $args")}` Not sure how well this would work as e.g. a git editor, but at least on the command line it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks Markus! That's a great trick, will add it to the https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup page

Comment: Given this is the PATH environmental variable, it might be that you need to restart PowerShell or perhaps log off / log in. `code` in PowerShell works for me

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, VS Code these days seems to have a Command Palette (shift + Cmd + P) command to install it to the path called "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH".

Comment: Apparently this is only a thing on macOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_launching-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Modern Software Installation.

Many of the larger software packages have finally caught-up with the times.  Make sure the correct choice(s) are made during the software download and during the software installation.

Most individual PC users are the sole users of their PCs.  Yet many software packages have always defaulted the installation processes to assume otherwise.  This is why so many software packages install to a path that includes C:\ .... user\ ...

But most of us individual PC users don't want the software installation including a path that involves using the ... user\ ...  path.  And instead we want the software installed into the default C:\  path without the "user name".

Some of the most common software installation packages are becoming available for the individual PC user and these packages install on the PC in our preferred path  - (not involving a path through the ... user\ ... ).

And if there is not a separate download package for the individual PC user, then during installation make sure to closely read each step which will often now include a checkbox of whether the installation is for a "user" or for "all users".  Select all users.